the image in my document has undesirable white space
The image in my document has undesirable white space, I want to remove the extra whitespace:
I use \includegraphics as follows:
\section*{section :}
\begin{wrapfigure}{i}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm, height=4cm]{ENS}
        \caption{This is the Overleaf logo}
    \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum

The output is the image below


Start by removing the center env, it adds vertical space.

Do not specify both width and height that distorts the image. Use width =\linewidth  to make it as wide as your insert

Usually is a bad idea mix absolute lengths (e.g.: 5cm) with relative lengths (e.g. 0.5\textwidth).  You do not show a complete document, so nobody can guess what mean really  \textwidth here. Always post a minimal but working example (i.e., compilable "as is").  By default \textwidth value is 345pt, so, in this case means ask to leave a space of 172,5pt for an image of 5cm=142,3pt, but in your case it seems that \textwidth is much more. Type \the\textwidth somewhere in the text to find out how much more it is.

To long for the comment ...
Consider comments to your question you may adapt the following MWE (Minimal Working Example) to your real document (you not provide any information about it):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\parskip{1ex}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=0.25\baselineskip,
            font=footnotesize,
            labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}                % or novel `wrapfig2`, if you prefer to enable
                                    % features not used in this particular case
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure} %
   {\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}    % remove vertical space above content of 
                                    % "wrapfig" at paragraphs, which aren't 
                                    % follows section titles

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{l}{4cm}  % [8]: number of texts' lines spans by wrapfig
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{This is the Overleaf logo}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{l}{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{This is the Overleaf logo}
\end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}



What about the wrapfig2 package?

@EmanueleNardi, in this particular case is not difference if you use wrapfig or wrapfig2 package. With bot you will get the same result. of course, withwrapfig2 you have more features for wrapping text, figures, tables etc.
